# Dropbox detect file change using delta IOS

Tags: ios, dropbox

I want the user to be advised if any file changes in the dropbox folder. To do this I have to use this code:

```
[self.restCLient loadDelta: nil];
```

and the methods:

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedDeltaEntries:(NSArray *)entries reset:(BOOL)shouldReset cursor:(NSString *)cursor hasMore:(BOOL)hasMore{
NSLog(@"WORKED: %@, %@, %c, %c", entries, cursor, hasMore, shouldReset);
 }

 -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadDeltaFailedWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"THE ERROR: %@", error);
}
```

This is the type of response I am getting:

```
2013-03-06 20:46:33.373 Splash-it[1659:907] WORKED: (
"<DBDeltaEntry: 0x1e2afbf0>",
"<DBDeltaEntry: 0x1e0e4030>",
"<DBDeltaEntry: 0x1e013640>",
"<DBDeltaEntry: 0x1e28e590>"
)
```

How can I understand form this if something has changed in my dropbox?

Comment: Is all these delta entries related to your files?

Comment: @PratikSomaiya Yes they are...

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I thought I'd answer anyway. :)

You're going to want to access the properties of the `DBDeltaEntry` object.

**Step 1: Import DBDeltaEntry.h**

I have no idea why this isn't included with the rest of the Dropbox stuff (I emailed Dropbox to ask why). Add this to your class:

```
#import "DBDeltaEntry.h"
```

**Step 2: Loop Through the Results**

Inside the `loadedDeltaEntries` delegate method, you can loop through your results like this:

```
for(DBDeltaEntry *file in entries) {
  NSLog(@"Entry name: %@ / Metadata: %@",file.lowercasePath, file.metadata.filename);
}
```

To see what else you can access on the metadata of an DBDeltaEntry object, look inside DBMetadata.h:

```
BOOL thumbnailExists;
long long totalBytes;
NSDate* lastModifiedDate;
NSDate *clientMtime; // file's mtime for display purposes only
NSString* path;
BOOL isDirectory;
NSArray* contents;
NSString* hash;
NSString* humanReadableSize;
NSString* root;
NSString* icon;
NSString* rev;
long long revision; // Deprecated; will be removed in version 2. Use rev whenever possible
BOOL isDeleted;

NSString *filename;
```

**Step 3: Understanding The Results**

This list of entries represents the most recent changes to your Dropbox folder (what files were modified, deleted, or added). Using the `cursor` is important in the `loadedDeltaEntries` method because it helps you keep track of which changes you're aware of. You can store the cursor and then pass it in with each delta call to tell Dropbox "this is as far as I'm aware when it comes to changes" and Dropbox will only tell you what has changed since that cursor.

I hope that helps.